# Limit of $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}(1+x)^k$

Tags: limits

In one book, it says that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}(1+x)^k=1+kx$, for any $k$. But why?

At least for positive integers, I would expect that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}(1+x)^k=1$, using binomial theorem. The same for the negative integers$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}(1+x)^k=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{(1+x)^{-k}}=\frac{1}{(1+0)^{-k}}=1.$$

Comment: The book is wrong, very very wrong. What book is this?

Comment: A Practical Guide To Quantitative Finance Interviews by Xinfeng Zhou, page 34.

Comment: What is true is $(1+x)^{k} \sim 1+kx$ as $x \to 0$ but writing in the form in which it is written in the book is not acceptable.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Yes, of course. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, the result $$\lim_{x\to 0} \, (1+x)^k = 1$$
holds for all $k\in \mathbb R$, not just $k\in \mathbb Z$. The proof is straightforward if you notice that the exponentiation map $\psi_k(x) = x^k$ is continuous for any $k\in \mathbb R$. You can also resort to the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity and work this out from scratch. In particular, try to bound $$|(1+x)^k - 1|$$
using the Taylor series expansion of $(1+x)^k$ near $0$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249052/expansion-of-1x-alpha) post).

Comment: You can also use the property for the limit of a product since $k$ is fixed and finite.

Comment: @Lelouch Unfortunately, that works only for $k\in \mathbb Z$. I claim that the results holds for $k\in \mathbb R$ also.

Answer (score 2):

The wording of the book is wrong.

I think it want to say $(1+x)^k \approx 1+kx$ for small x. It is a common approximation used frequently.

It should not use limit, the limit is just $1$.

Or, it should say $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(1+x)^k-1}{x}=k$

Answer (score 1):

The statement is incorrect in way the book has chosen to express it, but its gist is true.

We immediately see that the equation seems incorrect since the "$x$" in the expression on the left is [*bound*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) within the limit operator, while the "$x$" on the right is *free*. In effect, the free variable $x$ on the RHS behaves like a variable in the conventional sense, and we could choose to substitute it for some value (say, setting $x=2.7$). However, the bound variable $x$ on the LHS has more of a syntactic role as a companion to the $\lim$ operator; it expresses a determined course, "$x$ is approaching $0$", and we are not at liberty to assign the variable a value.

Evidently, if we are able to choose the value of $x$ on the RHS but *not* the LHS, it seems that something is amiss.* A fundamental property of equality is that anything true for one side should be true for the other! It is clear, however, that the book is trying to convey the correct idea that the LHS and RHS become closer together somehow as $x$ approaches $0$. So, some potential, more correct ways, we could express that fact are:

1. $(1+x)^k \color{red}{\approx} 1+kx$ near $x=0$. The expressions are *approximately equal*. This, unlike the following two relations, is not strict due to the inherent vagueness of "approximately", but regardless it is plain in its meaning and easily understandable.
2. $(1+x)^k \color{red}{=} 1 + kx \color{red}{+\mathcal{O}(x^{2})}$ (as $x\to0$). Here, we describe the *error term* of the approximation as *big O* or *small O* of some order. The details are fiddly and there are countless resources online explaining big O notation, so I won't go into it here. But suffice it to say that this relation expresses that the difference between the two sides behaves like $x^2$, and vanishes that quickly as $x$ approaches $0$.
3. $(1+x)^k \color{red}{\sim} 1+kx$ (as $x\to0$). The expressions are *asymptotically equal*. It expresses that the ratio between the two expressions approaches $1:1$ as $x$ approaches $0$, that is, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x)^k}{1+kx}=1$. In essence, this means that both sides head into their value at $x=0$ at matching rates. More specifically, they do so on the same *order* (here, linearly).

As a concluding remark, the RHS can be seen as a power series expansion of the LHS, truncated to the linear term. The subsequent terms in the expansion (i.e., what the approximation's error term hides) can be found with the binomial series.

---

* For completeness, a formula like this could still arguably be true if the free variable's expression is constant wrt. the variable, such that we have $\text{const.} = \text{const.}$ and our assignment of any values is inconsequential. But regardless, in general, it is bad practice to use a variable as *both* free and bound within the same formula or expression, for instance, $\displaystyle\int_0^x x\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer!